# What race does Vishnu kill the most of?

Tags: vishnu

What race does Vishnu kill the most of? Which is the race that most frequently causes the need for its individuals to be destroyed.

Comment: You answered your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far it has to be humans. Krshna kills twenty-three akshauhinîs in one go. He makes it clear he is responsible and he could have avoided by just killing the leader (who was spared to produce more armies, presumably for him to destroy).

> S'rî S'uka said: 'Asti and Prâpti, the two queens of Kamsa, oh hero of the Bhâratas, were unhappy that their husband had been killed and in distress went to their father's house. (2) They told their father, the king of Magadha named Jarâsandha [see also 1.15: 9, 9.22: 8, 10.2: 1-2, 10.36: 36], everything about the cause of their widowhood. (3) Hearing those bad tidings, oh King, he full of sorrow and indignation embarked upon the extreme endeavor of ridding the earth of the Yâdavas. (4) With twenty-three akshauhinîs he amassed around Mathurâ to besiege the royal capital of the Yadus on all sides. (5-6) When Krishna, the Supreme Lord Hari, saw how his army, like an ocean that overflowed its boundaries, besieged His city and filled His subjects with fear, He as the Ultimate Cause in a Human Form, considered what, to the purpose of His descent into this world, would be the best course of action considering the time and place: (7-8) '**I will surely annihilate his army**, this burden of the earth gathered by the king of Magadha, in which he brought together all who, subservient to him, have assumed leadership and now can be counted in akshauhinîs of infantry, cavalry, chariotry and elephantry. **Jarâsandha however, I should spare so that he again will try to assemble an army**. (9) For this purpose I have descended: to remove the burden of this earth, to protect the virtuous souls and put an end to the rest [that is bad]. (10) As soon as after a certain period of time injustice predominates I, in order to protect the dharma, also assume other bodies [see also 2.7 and B.G. 4: 7].'

Twenty-three akshauhinîs is 23*218700= 5,030,100 men. In addition, Kalki kills almost everyone (with Devapi and Maru the only named survivors and possibly the only actual human survivors).

> And Markandeya said,
>
> ...
>
> (Markandeya continued, )
>
> ...
>
> And commissioned by Time, a Brahmana of the name of Kalki will take his birth. And he will glorify Vishnu and possess great energy, great intelligence, and great prowess. And he will take his birth in a town of the name of Sambhala in an auspicious Brahmana family. And vehicles and weapons, and warriors and arms, and coats of mail will be at his disposal as soon as he will think of them. And he will be the king of kings, and ever victorious with the strength of virtue.
>
> And he will restore order and peace in this world crowded with creatures and contradictory in its course. And that blazing Brahmana of mighty intellect, having appeared, will destroy all things. And **he will be the Destroyer of all**, and will inaugurate a new Yuga. And surrounded by the Brahmanas, that Brahmana will exterminate all the mlecchas wherever those low and despicable persons may take refuge.

So that's at least 7.9 billion, although likely more as this is in the future. The only thing that comes close is if you conservatively count half of the number of Asuras in Lanka as being killed by Rama (for women, children, non-fighters). This incredibly unrealistic figure is 50 billion.

> “Ten thousand kotis of titans, able to change their form at will, feeding on flesh and blood, inhabit Lanka. At their head, their sovereign the wicked Ravana made war on the supporters of the earth as also the Gods who were all overcome by him.”

However, the actual army of Lanka is probably closer to 2 billion using the ratio of cavalry in an akshauhini and sixty kotis of horses. If we double it to account for losses that already occurred it is 4 billion.

> At this command, Mahaparshva gave his orders to the army leaders, who were present, saying:—

> Instantly all the titans of grim aspect ran out with a formidable clamour, carrying every kind of weapon in their hands. Swords, lances, clubs, maces, hammers, Halas, spears with sharp points, huge Kutamudgaras, harpoons of every kind, discus, pointed Parashvas, Bhindipalas, Shataghnis and various other arms. Thereafter four officers under his command, brought a hundred thousand chariots to Ravana and three hundred thousand elephants, **sixty kotis of horses**, mules and buffalo and innumerable foot soldiers, all hastening there at the king’s command.

In reality, the population density of humans at the end of Kali Yuga will be similar to Lanka under Ravana but over a much wider space (even possibly beyond Earth) due to humans getting technology at comparable, if only in name, to the Asuras.

As a side note their ability to change form at will probably indicates they are shapeshifting Devas, rather than natural Asuras.

As a further side note, Asuras can revive the dead, so their deaths are not as meaningful as human ones.

https://bhagavata.org/canto10/chapter50.html

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424725.html

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc7469.html

https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-ramayana-of-valmiki/d/doc424647.html